# Beveling with tight geometry

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, bevel

I've recently purchased a copy of HOps/BoxCutter and I have been loving them so far - however, I've run into an issue where when I have tight geometry made by boxcutter, I am basically incapable of using a bevel modifier across the model. I was looking for some advice on how best I can approach this problem in order to fully bevel the model as desired.

Here's an example photo of my model. [image: Example Model]

and additionally, a view of the geometry of the model.
[image]

If you prefer the model, you can get the .blend here:
[image]

Comment: Check out Josh Gambrell. His channel is basically dedicated to fixing boolean and bevel issues. His videos will teach you the best ways of finding and fixing the exact issues you refer to.
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXfGjwohMgPm4Ng2e1FXySw

Comment: on what part are you not able to create bevel exactly?

Comment: @moonboots I believe right now the main factor causing bevel issues is being caused by this section of the model: https://i.imgur.com/IgIOhA8.png

Comment: @Psyonic I've been watching Josh's videos and that's what motivated me to get the plugins originally. However, I cannot seem to find a video for fixing this specific issue - I know it exists, he just has a lot of content!

Comment: @primelf I'm not the right one to help with this, but you can consider to attach blend file to see what is happening (yet not clear from your screens). Use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and paste given code into your question. In some cases could be better use bevelling by node in render. And last note -you have also issue in right-bottom part of front face with normals shading.

Comment: @vklidu I am aware of the normals shading, I decided that was a problem for later when I have everything fully modeled. Do you have a suggestion to fix it? I've also gone ahead and added the `.blend` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beveling such thing is not an easy, because of small cuts (like objects under Boolean.003, .007, .008). Beveled edges starts to overlap. So you can use only some small range, but even with the value 0.003 it is overlapping. You can notice that since bevelling doesn't appear until you disable *Clamp Overlap* under *Geometry* or disable mentioned modifiers.

[image]

If you need bevel bigger radius in some areas than others (like bigger radius on base shape and smaller on smaller cuts) move Bevel Modifier up in modifier's stack and use another one.
You would have to use probably some limitations, like *Vertex Group* for those vertices. But Vertex Group can be set only when modifiers are applied, means destructive way.

---

Some decent bevelling can be achieved with material **Bevel** node.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's worth noting the Bevel node effect is only available with Cycles Render Engine